# Is it possible to delete old records from clickhouse table?

Tags: sql, clickhouse

As far as I know, clickhouse allows only inserting new data. But is it possible to delete block older then some period to avoid overflow of HDD?

Comment: to auto-remove old-records consider using [TTL](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/engines/table_engines/mergetree_family/mergetree/#table_engine-mergetree-ttl)-feature of CH

Answer (score 51, accepted):

## Lightweight delete

*Available since v22.8*

Standard DELETE syntax for MergeTree tables has been introduced in [#37893](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/pull/37893).

```sql
SET allow_experimental_lightweight_delete = 1;
DELETE FROM merge_table_standard_delete WHERE id = 10;
```

## Altering data using Mutations

See the docs on Mutations feature https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/query_language/alter/#mutations.
The feature was implemented in Q3 2018.

### Delete data

```
ALTER TABLE <table> DELETE WHERE <filter expression>
```

#### "Dirty" delete all

You always have to specify a *filter expression*. If you want to delete all the data through Mutation, specify something that's always true, eg.:

```sql
ALTER TABLE <table> DELETE WHERE 1=1
```

### Update data

It's also possible to mutate (`UPDATE`) the similar way

```
ALTER TABLE <table> UPDATE column1 = expr1 [, ...] WHERE <filter expression>
```

### Mind it's async

Please note that all commands above do not execute the data mutation directly (in sync). Instead they schedule ClickHouse Mutation that is executed independently (async) on background. That is the reason why `ALTER TABLE` syntax was chosen instead of typical SQL `UPDATE`/`DELETE`. You can check unfinished Mutations' progress via

```sql
SELECT *
FROM system.mutations
WHERE is_done = 0
```

#### ...unless

you change [`mutations_sync` settings](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#mutations_sync) to

- `1` so it synchronously waits for current server
- `2` so it waits for all replicas

## Altering data without using Mutations

Theres's `TRUNCATE TABLE` statement with syntax as follows:

```sql
TRUNCATE TABLE [IF EXISTS] [db.]name [ON CLUSTER cluster]
```

This synchronously truncates the table. It will check for table size so won't allow you to delete if table size exceeds `max_table_size_to_drop`. See docs here:

https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/sql-reference/statements/truncate/

Comment: Instead of `delete where 1=1` which adds a mutation, I've been using `TRUNCATE TABLE <table>` which synchronously removes all data from table without adding mutation

Comment: Changing `mutations_sync` to 1 can make delete/update synchronous https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#mutations_sync

Answer (score 3):

Example to create and delete partition

```
    CREATE TABLE test.partitioned_by_month(d Date, x UInt8) ENGINE = MergeTree 

PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(d) ORDER BY x;

    INSERT INTO test.partitioned_by_month VALUES ('2000-01-01', 1), ('2000-01-02', 2), ('2000-01-03', 3);

INSERT INTO test.partitioned_by_month VALUES ('2000-02-03', 4), ('2000-02-03', 5);

INSERT INTO test.partitioned_by_month VALUES ('2000-03-03', 4), ('2000-03-03', 5);

SELECT * FROM test.partitioned_by_month;

---d------------|-------x-----

 2000-02-03 | 4 

 2000-02-03 | 5 


---d------------|-------x-----

 2000-03-03 | 4 

 2000-03-03 | 5 

---d------------|-------x-----

 2000-01-01 | 1 

 2000-01-02 | 2

 2000-01-03 | 3 

ALTER TABLE test.partitioned_by_month DROP PARTITION 200001;

select * from partitioned_by_month;


---d------------|-------x-----

 2000-03-03 | 4 

 2000-03-03 | 5 

---d------------|-------x-----


 2000-02-03 | 4 

 2000-02-03 | 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Clickhouse doesn't have update/Delete feature like Mysql database. But we still can do delete by organising data in the partition.I dont know how u r managing data so i am taking here an example like one are storing data in a monthwise partition.

By using "DROP PARTITION" command you can delete the data of that month by Droping the partition of that month, here is the complete explanation of how to Drop partition https://clickhouse.yandex/blog/en/how-to-update-data-in-clickhouse.