# What could prevent me from deleting data from a clickhouse database?

Tags: database, clickhouse, alter

I would like to delete **a subset of the data** contained in a clickhouse database rather than truncating the entire database. I am aware of the syntax relying on mutations described [in this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52355143/is-it-possible-to-delete-old-records-from-clickhouse-table) or [in this SO comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69624115/delete-some-data-in-clickhouse-like-in-mysql).

For instance to delete the data associated with **myid** 42 from table **mytable**:

```
ALTER TABLE mytable DELETE WHERE myid = 42
```

This works as expected on a database hosted on a Linux VM (Ubuntu 18.04.5) under Clickhouse 20.11.2.1.

However, this command does not delete the data from a database hosted on a different Linux VM hosted on Azure (also Ubuntu 18.04.5) under Clickhouse 21.2.5.5.

Regardless of whether deletion is successfull or not, clickhouse does not return any error message, simply the **Query id** followed by **Ok**.

**What could cause this issue?** **How can it be fixed?**

Comment: 21.2 is out support.

Comment: https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/18804

Comment: If mutations does not work at all it could be that you have configured background poll with 0 threads available for mutations

Comment: depends on engine. Different problems with Replicated and not Replicated.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Denny. Do you know if this issue has been addressed in more recent versions of Clickhouse?

Answer (score 1):

`ALTER TABLE ... DELETE` is a ***mutation***. At Clickhouse mutations are asynchronous by default. So you data will be deleted with some background process (and not atomically). Probably you should wait.

Other option is to use *mutations_sync* setting: https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/settings/settings/#mutations_sync . With that your request hangs until the data will be deleted (or until request_timeout)

Comment: Thanks for your reply Andrew. I am not sure whether waiting will fix the issue. It is true that one of the tables that I am working with is large (~8M rows), but I face similar issues with a smaller table (~44K rows) for which I expect the process to run quickly. Or maybe is the processing time not related to the size of the table?

Comment: For sure it may depends on size of the table. Also it may depends on how much rows are you deleting. Technically, `ALTER DELETE` (in the worst case) is performed by rewriting all the data (except that rows that you want to delete). So , deletion of one row may be very bad. Also, `DELETES` are not recommended for regular use, only in rare cases.

Comment: "Technically, ALTER DELETE (in the worst case) is performed by rewriting all the data". Thanks for this helpful comment: I was not aware that `ALTER` was working this way! `mutations_sync` does not seem like a very efficient way to remove a handful of rows either but at least it may allow to monitor when the rewriting is complete.

Comment: You also can watch the progress in `system.mutations` table. `SELECT * from system.mutations where not is_done` will show you all not finished mutations

Answer (score 0):

The answer proposed by Andrei Koch is correct in the sense that the mutation takes some time.

However, my problem was related to **the size of the table** to alter.

**[max_table_size_to_drop](https://clickhouse.com/docs/en/operations/server-configuration-parameters/settings/)** is a Clickhouse server configuration parameter set to 50Gb. The table that I was trying to alter was larger (56Gb) than this default threshold, thus preventing deletion from working correctly. Changing the server settings fixed this issue.